# Upload file using java in ftp

Tags: java

I want to upload file from my system to remote server as ftp.how i am to resolve this.I am using `FTPClient client = new FTPClient(); and client.connect("sftp://something.com");`But i am unable to connect  it how i am check weather problem with my code or url.like ping  command

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not as clear as desired. A piece of code and stack traces would be more informative

Comment: You write "I am unable to connect": what error do you get? Are your local system (client) behind a proxy?

Comment: do you have to login in the server? can you ping the adress?

Comment: i have login details  to that server.How to ping that address??Which commands are there??

Comment: i am able to ping that address  igot following C:\Documents and Settings\venkat>ping download.navteq.com

Pinging download.navteq.com [193.67.103.6] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 193.67.103.6:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used `FTPClient` (assume you mean [Apache Commons FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) but a quick browse of apidocs shows two errors in your use:

1. The parameter to connect is server name, not url: `client.connect("sftp://something.com")` should be `client.connect("something.com")`
2. If you are using sftp you have to use [FTPSClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to an Sftp you might need to add the appropriate certificates (public/private keys) to the JVM where the code is running. Try your code on a regular FTP connection first, if that works, but not the sftp connections, it's almost sure is because of that.